# Bounding a function of a matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I have a real positive quantity $f(A)= tr[A^{-1} (\partial_x A)  A^{-1} (\partial_x A)] + 2v^T A^{-1} v$ where $x$ is a real parameter and $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Let us assume that $S$ is a shift matrix (possibly a function of x) such that $A + S$ is symmetric

$$f(A + S)= tr[(A + S)^{-1} \partial_x (A + S)  (A + S)^{-1} \partial_x (A + S)] + 2v^T (A + S)^{-1} v.$$

How can one prove or disprove that $f(A) \le f(A+S)$?

Comment: What do you mean by shift matrix? What are the properties of $A$ and $S$? Are both of them invertible? Are they positive definite? If they are general symmetric matrices, you won't be able to establish any relation between $f(A)$ and $f(A+S)$...

Comment: @Daniel thanks, and yes both $A$ and $S$ are positive definite. By "shift" I simply meant that $A$ is "shifted" by a quantity given by $S$.